# How to transfer data from one Fragment to another?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-navigation

I am writing an application on Kotlin (Android Studio), using jetpack.navigation architecture.
There are two fragments: The first contains a list with class instances, which I display in the RecyclerView, the second for EditText (I fill in the client data). I also use Livedata and ViewModel.
The problem is that when I go to the second fragment, fill in the data and confirm, I go to the 1st fragment. As I understand it, the following lines destroy the old Fragment1, and create a new one. the list on the first fragment is reset to zero (although the list is saved when you rotate the screen and minimize the application).

```
 val client = Clients(id,name,secondName,thirdName, address, creditCard, bankNum)
 val action = Fragment2Directions.actionFragment2ToFragment1(client)
 findNavController().navigate(action)
```

I could not find how to solve problem using the navigation component. I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass data between two fragments  with jetpack  navigation you have to use [Safe Args](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data)

pass an argument section like

```
 <fragment android:id="@+id/myFragment" >
     <argument
         android:name="myArg"
         app:argType="integer"
         android:defaultValue="0" />
 </fragment>
```

add `classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"`  in top level gradle file

and add the plugin `apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"` 
now send the value like so

```
override fun onClick(v: View) {
   val amountTv: EditText = view!!.findViewById(R.id.editTextAmount)
   val amount = amountTv.text.toString().toInt()
   val action = SpecifyAmountFragmentDirections.confirmationAction(amount)
   v.findNavController().navigate(action)
}
```

and receive it as

```
val args: ConfirmationFragmentArgs by navArgs()

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val tv: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewAmount)
    val amount = args.amount
    tv.text = amount.toString()
}
```

**However safeargs works only for primitive types so you have to deconstruct and reconstruct if you're trying to pass Objects**

Comment: Now I get it, thanks a lot. But what the correct way to transfer Objects between fragments.

Comment: The correct way to transfer objects is implementing parcelable and bundles. The thing to keep in mind is the transfer to different fragments has to be done via the activity . Also if the answer helped you make sure to accept it.:)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `ViewModel`s, I recommend that you use a **shared ViewModel**. The way it works is that multiple Fragments within the same Activity have access to the same ViewModel instance.

There is an [example on Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html#sharing) that fits your use case exactly. It shows how to use a shared ViewModel to do this using the master-detail navigation pattern and `LiveData`. I recommend you take a look at it.

**Why not to use Safe Args here:** You *can* try using Safe Args to achieve what you are trying to achieve, but I strongly recommend against it: You would have to deal with somehow using Safe Args to pass your `Client` objects between the Fragments back and forth (which means either sending each field individually or bundling) and you would have to manually update your `LiveData` objects - which defeats the purpose of LiveData. Using a shared `ViewModel`, you do not have to worry about any of that. No sending data back and forth, no taking your `Client` objects apart or bundling, no manual updating of `LiveData` objects - you simply access the same `LiveData` instance from both Fragments through your `ViewModel`.